# Sitefinity: How to set page title based-on the content item being viewed?

Tags: sitefinity

I have a page in Sitefinity 7 and its entire purpose is to show the detailed view of a custom content item.

So I've dragged-on a widget to the page, selected that it only shows one particular item only, without selecting which, because it should be whatever one was chosen from another page which caused them to navigate here.

[image: One not-selected content item]

*One not-selected content item.*

[image: List widget navigates to the detail page]

*The page with the list control navigates to the detailed page.*

[image: Bad title]

But the page title is the same no-matter which is selected. I want the page title to be one of the content item's fields. **How can I get the page title to be based-on the item we're viewing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the Awards widget on your details page and then go to the Advanced settings, then in the MetaTitle field enter the field name of your module you'd like to use, so in most cases "Title", then in the PageTitleMode field, you can enter one of a few options, Append, Replace or DoNotSet. Documentation on those options is [here](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/bugs-issues-/news-widget-changing-pagetitle). You can also utilize the MetaKeywordsField and MetaDecriptionField by also mapping those to a new "SEO Keywords" or "SEO Description" long text field on your module for instance. Documentation on that is [here](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/automatic-generation-of-meta-keywords-and-meta-description-tags).

[image]

The screenshot is from Sitefinity 6.3 but it should be the same.

Comment: Thanks! Up-vote my question if you think it was clear and useful.

Comment: Shame there's no "Prepend" option.